# How can I make my mouse clicks louder?

Tags: technology, sound, plastics

My old mouse was pretty loud so bought a new one, now it is too quiet. Any hacks to make it louder?

Comment: Do you mean the physical mouse sound, or the software sound that some computers make? Also, for my personal curiousity: why do you want a loud mouse?

Comment: @mr_potato : For reducing the sound of your old mouse, you bought new one and now you require to increase the new mouses too? Please specify the issue as both these are contradictions.

Comment: lolz, I Google "mouse clicks" I thought it is something related to mouse (the rat) . Feeling stupid now :P

Comment: There's probably software you could load that would play a sound through the computer's sound system when you click, but that's really more suitable for another SE site -- which one depends on what operating system you use.

Comment: I like this question! Can you provide a picture or other description of your mouse? That'd help us help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/120204-assign-sounds-to-mouse-clicks/) to add a sound to every mouse click.

> ~LButton down::SoundPlay, E:\sounds\ldown.wav
>
> Check out the Key List to find the names of the keys. I believe they are LButton, RButton, MButton, WheelUp, WheelDown.
>
> The SoundPlay command can play a sound file for you. WAV should be the perfect format for this.
>
> The ~ modifier in front of the button tells AHK to let the active window receive the keypress (or mouse button in this case) while still doing the AHK script. And the "down" modifier tells AHK to do this when the key is down. The counterpart to that is "up".

Answer (score 0):

Buy a louder mouse. Adding anything underneath the mouse buttons would probably only increase the resistance of the buttons when trying to click, and may also prevent you from fully clicking. Additionally, if you care about warranties at all, opening up the mouse probably voids a warranty if there is one.

The good news is that mice are cheap.

Comment: This isn't a life hack to "buy new".